# How to pass row ID to another page using process.php?

Tags: php

I have this piece of code where I query all the rows of data from my database. In my 1st php, I have this link where I will pass the ID from the row into another php page. Here is my code.

```
<a class="button3" style="float: left;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" href="adminEditBillboard.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

My adminEditBillboard.php has this on a input type text.

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="owner" placeholder="Enter billboard owner name">
```

Do I need to add something? like a method post?

This is from my process.php for the edit.

```
 if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM billboards WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error);
    if(isset($result->num_rows) && $result->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $owner = $row['owner'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        header("location: adminEditBillBoard.php?edit=$id");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adminEditBillboard.php should pick the id from the HTTP GET parameters as follows

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $_GET['edit']; ?>" name="owner" placeholder="Enter billboard owner name">
```

Comment: I will put update on my question sir, showing my process.php for edit. please check sir

Comment: from where do you pass data to process.php?

Comment: from my first php page sir. the one with the href. do i need to put form action in it?

Comment: The first page is pointing to adminEditBillboard.php, not the process.php